# How to cut off a part of a String and add it as the ComboBox.Value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel Macro that holds a specific Value in its ActiveCell.
I want to add that Value as the ComboBox.Value but I need it to be added with a condition.

The way the ActiveCell Value looks like for Example:

```
13:00 - 14:00 [every two weeks] [KW12]
```

or

```
15:00 - 17:30 [weekly]
```

Now I need to check if that ActiveCell Value contains "*KW*" and if it does that "[KW12]" part needs to be cut away from the string.

I tried to do it with the Split() function but with no luck. (I could post the code I tried but maybe you have an easier method since I am not a VBA-Specialist)

The Code that sets the ActiveCell Value to be the ComboBox.Value:

```
If (Len(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) > 15) Then
     UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, 16, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) - 16) 
     
End If
```

That works but it always adds the whole ActiveCell Value so if there is a "KW" it would get added. I need a simple IF that checks for the Value to contain "*KW*" and if it does that cut of that part which usally should be the last 6 digits of the string because its always [KWxx]

The way that I can check for the ActiveCell to contain KW is like this:

```
If (ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Like "*KW*") Then
```

Comment: You could use: `Trim$(Left$(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, instr(1, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value & "[KW", "[KW") - 1))` for example.

Comment: Is the [KW12] the last position in the cell and is the Number after KW always 2 digits long?

Comment: Yes [KWxx] is always the last position in the activecell if it is set and its always 2 digitsd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I got it - the whole Split thing is way to complicated for what I need I guess I can just use this for KW Case:

```
UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, 16, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) - 22)
```

instead of this for non KW case

```
UserForm1.ComboBox5.Value = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, 16, Len(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value) - 16)
```

because it will always be the last 6 so that way it gets cut off the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

Split is a simpler solution

```
Split(ActiveCell.Value,"[KW")
```

The code above will return a variant containing an array of strings.  Everything before the first occurrence of "[KW" will be in the index 0 position in the array, other text, after the "[KW", will be in index positions 1 onwards (if there is more than one occurrence of "[KW".  If "[KW" is not in the ActiveCell.Value then index position 0 will just contain the input string.

Thus

```
Split(ActiveCell.Value,"[KW")(0)
```

will always work to give the text before the position of "[KW" or the whole input string if "[KW" is not present.  In the example above we are just extracting the value at index position zero of the array returned by the Split method, hence the (0) at the end of the statement.

You might then wrap that in a Trim$ to remove any spaces leading up to the "[KW"

```
UserForm1.ComboBox.Value = Trim$( Split( ActiveCell.Value,"[KW" )(0) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will use my own approach for now but its good to see how to split correctly so I have a reference for that later if I need it.